# pagination not working in second page

Tags: codeigniter-3

From second page on wards pagination not working in my codeigniter app.In first page 10 records showing from second page clicking in query also limiy not coming

my controller:

```
       public function Viewlist() {
       //echo "hello"; die();
        $data['title'] = 'board';
        $data['currentpage'] = 'board';
        $resultCount = $this->board->list();
       //echo '<pre>'; print_r($resultCount); die();
       // Pagination start 
        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
        $data['records'] = $this->Dashboard->ViewD($this->perPageNum, $data['page']);


        $data['links'] = getPagination($this->perPageNum, $resultCount, site_url() . 'admin/dashboardList', 0);

}
```

My model:

```
    public function ViewD($limit = NULL, $start = NULL, $bookingsearch = NULL) {
      $sessionData = $this->session->userdata('userdata');

      $this->db->select(some query);

    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
    $this->db->order_by('Id','DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    //echo $this->db->last_query(); die('test');
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;
}
```

In second page limit not coming

Answer (score 0):

```
public function Viewlist()
```

You are calling controller function without passing offset. Kindly check the pagination docs and create a controller function which accepts offset as a parameter and that is how you will be able to show data on second page and further.